# If radio button selected, scroll up to the first line of radio

Tags: javascript

I have a long list of radio buttons. I am looking for a solution if a radio button is selected, the page scrolls to the beginning of the radio button.

**Detail:**

I have list of radio button like that:

```
<div class="form-check">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="flexRadioDefault" id="flexRadioDefault1">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="flexRadioDefault1">
    Default radio
  </label>
</div>
<div class="form-check">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="flexRadioDefault" id="flexRadioDefault2" checked>
  <label id="divtwo" onclick="myMenu()" class="form-check-label" for="flexRadioDefault2">
    Default checked radio
  </label>
</div>
```

Js file:

```
function myMenu() { document.getElementById("divFirst").scrollIntoView(); }
```

I am looking for a solution, if the user clicks on the first radio button, then the page scrolls to the beginning.
It does not scroll while I click, although I added `onclick`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onclick="myMenu()"` should be on checkbox not on Label:

```
<input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="flexRadioDefault" id="flexRadioDefault2" onclick="myMenu()">
```

Comment: You could also put the radio inside the label. The problem is that when you click the label, the click event is firing on the radio but not on the label because of how labels usually work. You can still get the click even to fire on the label by double clicking.